# query executed in HIVE but cannot see results

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh, hue

I am working in HIVE with twitter flume data. So far I have successfully created the table and loaded the data in also but when I want to run a query on that external table I get the following error.

> Bad status for request TFetchResultsReq(fetchType=0, operationHandle=TOperationHandle(hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None, operationType=0, operationId=THandleIdentifier(secret='#\xabp\xa3\xa7\x83K\xc6\x82\x94h\xc3\x99\xe4\x81\x01', guid='\xae\xb2\x9d\x19\xdc\xb2@i\xbc\\x85\xb4\xd0\xfe\x0cN')), orientation=4, maxRows=100): TFetchResultsResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=0, errorMessage="java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@19ee3d8e; line: 1, column: 2]", sqlState=None, infoMessages=["*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@19ee3d8e; line: 1, column: 2]:26:25", 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:463', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperationNextRowSet:OperationManager.java:294', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:fetchResults:HiveSessionImpl.java:769', 'sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl:invoke0:NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2', 'sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57', 'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43', 'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:606', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:78', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:36', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:63', 'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2', 'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:415', 'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1917', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:59', 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26:fetchResults::-1', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:fetchResults:CLIService.java:462', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:FetchResults:ThriftCLIService.java:694', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1553', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1538', 'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39', 'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39', 'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56', 'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615', 'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745', "*java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@19ee3d8e; line: 1, column: 2]:30:4", 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:getNextRow:FetchOperator.java:508', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:pushRow:FetchOperator.java:415', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask:fetch:FetchTask.java:140', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:getResults:Driver.java:2069', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:458', "*org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException:org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@19ee3d8e; line: 1, column: 2]:31:1", 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe:deserialize:JsonSerDe.java:174', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:getNextRow:FetchOperator.java:489', "*org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException:Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@19ee3d8e; line: 1, column: 2]:37:6", 'org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser:_constructError:JsonParser.java:1291', 'org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase:_reportError:JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385', 'org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase:_reportUnexpectedChar:JsonParserMinimalBase.java:306', 'org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser:_handleUnexpectedValue:Utf8StreamParser.java:1582', 'org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser:_nextTokenNotInObject:Utf8StreamParser.java:437', 'org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser:nextToken:Utf8StreamParser.java:323', 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe:deserialize:JsonSerDe.java:163'], statusCode=3), results=None, hasMoreRows=None)

Before this error HIVE gives me success query message but later on above error is shown and no results of any query are dispplayed. Can someone tell me where is my mistake and what is causing this error?

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: @MayankPorwal I am doing simple query like this select * from tweets

Comment: you should add, table creation, query, data (if possibl) expected results. does it happend the same if you limit the select ?

Comment: yes even if I use limit the result it happens for example select * from tweets limit 2

Comment: @hlagos do you think does it have to do anything with my flume data file becuase it also contains some garbage also....

Comment: yes, for sure. the most of json serdes for hive are sensible about the content

Comment: @hlagos any idea to get clear twitter data without garbage?

Comment: you need to share more than this. I would suggest create a new question with your flume configuration, input data, expected results, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Set use_get_log_api=true in the beeswax section of the hue.ini configuration file.

After change the hue.ini file run below commands to restart the hive server, I will not work otherwise.

sudo service hive-server2 stop
sudo service hue stop
sudo service hive-server2 start
sudo service hue start